# Trouble With .fit. Multi-Input Computer Vision Model with TensorFlow: Handling Images of Different Sizes (TFRecord Data)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

I have datasets for different image resolutions (192x192, 224x224, 331x331, and 512x512).
Each dataset includes images and corresponding labels.
I'm using the Xception pre-trained model as the base.
I'm utilizing a multi-input architecture where each resolution corresponds to a separate input branch.

My data:

```
def decode_image(image_data,target_size):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_data, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0  # convert image to floats in [0, 1] range
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*target_size, 3]) # explicit size needed for TPU
    return image

def read_labeled_tfrecord(example, target_size):
    LABELED_TFREC_FORMAT = {
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "class": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, LABELED_TFREC_FORMAT)
    image = decode_image(example['image'], target_size)
    label = tf.cast(example['class'], tf.int32)
    return image, label

def read_unlabeled_tfrecord(example, target_size):
    UNLABELED_TFREC_FORMAT = {
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "id": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, UNLABELED_TFREC_FORMAT)
    image = decode_image(example['image'], target_size)
    idnum = example['id']
    return image, idnum


def load_dataset(filenames, target_size, labeled=True, ordered=False):
    ignore_order = tf.data.Options()
    if not ordered:
        ignore_order.experimental_deterministic = False

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTO)
    dataset = dataset.with_options(ignore_order)
    
    if labeled:
        read_function = lambda x: read_labeled_tfrecord(x, target_size)
    else:
        read_function = lambda x: read_unlabeled_tfrecord(x, target_size)
    
    dataset = dataset.map(read_function, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)

    
    return dataset

def get_training_dataset(TRAINING_FILENAMES, image_size):
    dataset = load_dataset(image_size,TRAINING_FILENAMES, labeled=True)
    dataset = dataset.map(data_augment,num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    dataset = dataset.repeat() # the training dataset must repeat for several epochs
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO) # prefetch next batch while training (autotune prefetch buffer size)
    return dataset



def get_validation_dataset(VALIDATION_FILENAMES,image_size, ordered=False):
    dataset = load_dataset(image_size,VALIDATION_FILENAMES, labeled=True, ordered=ordered)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO)
    return dataset

def get_test_dataset(TEST_FILENAMES,image_size, ordered=False):
    dataset = load_dataset(image_size,
                           TEST_FILENAMES, labeled=False, ordered=ordered)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO)
    return dataset

ds_train_192 = get_training_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_192,TRAINING_FILENAMES_192)
ds_valid_192 = get_validation_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_192,VALIDATION_FILENAMES_192)
ds_test_192 = get_test_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_192,TEST_FILENAMES_192)

ds_train_224 = get_training_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_224, TRAINING_FILENAMES_224)
ds_valid_224 = get_validation_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_224,VALIDATION_FILENAMES_224)
ds_test_224 = get_test_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_224,TEST_FILENAMES_224)

ds_train_331 = get_training_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_331,TRAINING_FILENAMES_331)
ds_valid_331 = get_validation_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_331,VALIDATION_FILENAMES_331)
ds_test_331 = get_test_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_331,TEST_FILENAMES_331)

ds_train_512 = get_training_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_512,TRAINING_FILENAMES_512)
ds_valid_512 = get_validation_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_512,VALIDATION_FILENAMES_512)
ds_test_512 = get_test_dataset(IMAGE_SIZE_512,TEST_FILENAMES_512)
```

My model:

```
input_shape_192 = (192, 192, 3)
input_shape_224 = (224, 224, 3)
input_shape_331 = (331, 331, 3)
input_shape_512 = (512, 512, 3)



with strategy.scope():
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.Xception(
        weights='imagenet',
        include_top=False 
    )
    base_model.trainable = False

    image_input_192 = Input(shape=input_shape_192, name='192')
    image_input_224 = Input(shape=input_shape_224, name='224')
    image_input_331 = Input(shape=input_shape_331, name='331')
    image_input_512 = Input(shape=input_shape_512, name='512')
    
    features_192 = base_model(image_input_192)
    features_224 = base_model(image_input_224)
    features_331 = base_model(image_input_331)
    features_512 = base_model(image_input_512)
    
    flatten_192 = Flatten()(features_192)
    flatten_224 = Flatten()(features_224)
    flatten_331 = Flatten()(features_331)
    flatten_512 = Flatten()(features_512)


    
    merged_features = Concatenate()([flatten_192, flatten_224, flatten_331, flatten_512])

    
    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(merged_features)

    output = Dense(len(CLASSES), activation='softmax')(x)
    
    model = Model(inputs=[image_input_192, image_input_224, image_input_331, image_input_512], outputs=output)
```

The problem occurs with `.fit`:

```
history = model.fit(
    [ds_train_192,ds_train_224, ds_train_331, ds_train_512],
    validation_data = [ds_valid_192,ds_valid_224, ds_valid_331, ds_valid_512]
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
    callbacks=[lr_callback, stop_callback],
)
```

`ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (\<class 'list'\> containing {"\<class 'str'\>"} keys and {"\<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.prefetch_op.\_PrefetchDataset'\>"} values), \<class 'NoneType'\>`

Same goes with dict when trying `{"192": ds_train_192, "224": ds_train_224, "331": ds_train_331, "512": ds_train_512 }`

How do i train model using images with different sizes?